# How to join Product and Product Variants to get every variant with product name

Tags: php, mysql, join

How to join Product and Product Variants to get every variant with product name. I'm getting all variants but my loop repeating product name each time with product variant.
My code is:

```
    public function viewAllProducts($user_id){
    $SelectProducts_Query = mysqli_query($this->conn, "SELECT smpr.product_id, smpr.user_id, smpr.product_name, smpr.product_sizes, smpr.product_photo, smpr.product_created, smpr.product_updated, smpq.quantity_id, smpq.quantity_product_id, smpq.quantity_user_id, smpq.quantity_available, smpq.quantity_price, smpq.quantity_cost, smpq.quantity_size_name FROM ssm_products_quantity as smpq inner join ssm_products as smpr on smpq.quantity_product_id=smpr.product_id WHERE smpr.user_id = $user_id order by smpr.product_id DESC");
    if($SelectProducts_Query){
        while($view_all_products = mysqli_fetch_array($SelectProducts_Query)){
            $view_all_products_details[] = array(
                "product_id" => $view_all_products["product_id"],
                "product_name" => $view_all_products["product_name"],
                "product_photo" => $view_all_products["product_photo"],
                "product_sizes" => $view_all_products["product_sizes"],
                "product_created_date" => $view_all_products["product_created"],
                "product_updated_date" => $view_all_products["product_updated"],
                "sizes" => array(
                    "size_id" => $view_all_products["quantity_id"],
                    "size_product_id" => $view_all_products["quantity_product_id"],
                    "size_available_id" => $view_all_products["quantity_available"]
                )
            );
        }
        return $view_all_products_details;
    }else{
        return $view_all_products_details = "false";
    }
}
```

right now I'm getting records like this:
[image]

I want to get records like this:

```
    {  
    "error":false,
    "products_detail":[  
        {  
            "product_id":"24",
            "product_name":"Miror",
            "product_photo":"product_images\/1-dummy-17-07-11-10-26-06.jpg",
            "product_sizes":"2",
            "product_created_date":"2017-07-11 13:26:06",
            "product_updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "sizes":{  
                "size_id":"1",
                "size_product_id":"24",
                "size_available_id":"50"
            },{  
                "size_id":"2",
                "size_product_id":"24",
                "size_available_id":"20"
            }
        },
        {  
            "product_id":"25",
            "product_name":"Pipes",
            "product_photo":"product_images\/1-pipes-17-07-11-10-22-08.jpg",
            "product_sizes":"2",
            "product_created_date":"2017-07-11 13:26:06",
            "product_updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "sizes":{  
                "size_id":"3",
                "size_product_id":"25",
                "size_available_id":"20"
            },{  
                "size_id":"4",
                "size_product_id":"25",
                "size_available_id":"20"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any solution for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use your product id as an array index

try this:

```
public function viewAllProducts($user_id){
  $SelectProducts_Query = mysqli_query($this->conn, "SELECT smpr.product_id, smpr.user_id, smpr.product_name, smpr.product_sizes, smpr.product_photo, smpr.product_created, smpr.product_updated, smpq.quantity_id, smpq.quantity_product_id, smpq.quantity_user_id, smpq.quantity_available, smpq.quantity_price, smpq.quantity_cost, smpq.quantity_size_name FROM ssm_products_quantity as smpq inner join ssm_products as smpr on smpq.quantity_product_id=smpr.product_id WHERE smpr.user_id = $user_id order by smpr.product_id DESC");
  if($SelectProducts_Query){
    while($view_all_products = mysqli_fetch_array($SelectProducts_Query)){
      $pid = $view_all_products["product_id"];
      //check the array for product with id is already exists,
      //if not then add the data to array[pid] without the sizes
      if(!isset($view_all_products_details[$pid]){
        $view_all_products_details[$pid] = array(
            "product_id" => $pid,
            "product_name" => $view_all_products["product_name"],
            "product_photo" => $view_all_products["product_photo"],
            "product_sizes" => $view_all_products["product_sizes"],
            "product_created_date" => $view_all_products["product_created"],
            "product_updated_date" => $view_all_products["product_updated"]
        );
      }
      //add the array "sizes" as multidimensional array
      //you can set the size_id as index too but i think it is not necessary
      $view_all_products_details[$pid]["sizes"][] = array(
          "size_id" => $view_all_products["quantity_id"],
          "size_product_id" => $view_all_products["quantity_product_id"],
          "size_available_id" => $view_all_products["quantity_available"]
      );
    }
    return $view_all_products_details;
  }else{
    return $view_all_products_details = "false";
  }
}
```

Comment: Can You Please Explain What You Did. It Will Be Helpful For Other's Seeker Too.

Comment: @Atmahadli, it works for me but I have a problem. The return statement shows an product ID as object after "products_detail" object. 

I want to remove this  "24": { 

from product details at line number (4, 24 etc) is this possible?

Image sample
http://i.imgur.com/skRg8jL.png

Comment: try this: `return array_merge($view_all_products_details);` read http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php **quoted note: numeric keys will be renumbered**